# How to get all the fan page from facebook using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have wrote a code for posting to a fan page in javascript and i am able to post it content to the fan page. But the page_id i gave is static. I want it to be dynamic. How can i get all the page_id from the FB which is related to the logined user and from where he can select the fan page where he want to post.

```
 ` function postToPage() {
          var page_id = '1426984900889247';
          FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
            if(resp.access_token) {
                FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                    'post',
                    { message: "{!posDetails.Name}",
                      description :'{!posDetails.CMSR__Job_Description__c}',
                      link : '{!siteUrl}',
                      picture: '{!posDetails.CMSR__Linked_In_Url__c}',
                      caption: '{!posDetails.CMSR__Summary__c}',
                      access_token: resp.access_token }
                     ,function(response) {
                     console.log(response);
                });
                }
            });
         }`
```

please guide me how can i achieve this issue.

Comment: You mean all the pages the user is admin of? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/

Comment: yes. all the pages where user in admin of